# Carbon diffForHumans showing 'ago' only

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

Input:

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$now->locale('en');
dump($now);
dump($now->isMutable());
dump($now->diffForHumans());
dump(Carbon::parse($now)->diffForHumans());
```

Output:

[image]

Versions from composer.json

```
"require": {
  "php": ">=7.1.3",
  "arcanedev/log-viewer": "^4.5",
  "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~3.0",
  "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.6",
  "beyondcode/laravel-websockets": "^1.3",
  "doctrine/dbal": "^2.10",
  "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
  "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
  "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
  "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
  "laravel/horizon": "^3.7.2",
  "laravel/passport": "^7.3",
  "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
  "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0",
  "lcobucci/jwt": "3.3.3",
  "mpdf/mpdf": "^8.0",
  "orangehill/iseed": "dev-master",
  "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*",
  "predis/predis": "^1.1",
  "proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation": "^2.0",
  "pusher/pusher-php-server": "~3.0",
  "twilio/sdk": "^5.36",
  "nesbot/carbon": "2.50.0 as 1.39.0",
  "kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2": "^1.0.0"
},
```

Comment: Hello, can you try to replace 2.50.0 with the latest release of nesbot/carbon: 2.57.0?

Comment: Yes, it is working fine now. Thank you.